# Why json.dumps() in python 3 return a different value of python 2?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, md5, python-3.6

I need to generate a MD5 Hash in Python 3 to compare with a MD5 Hash that was generated on Python 2, but the result for json.dumps() is different, because on Python 2 the position of the elements changes and the MD5 result is different.

How can I generate the same result?

*The code:*

```
content = {'name': 'Marcelo', 'age': 30, 'address': {'country': 'Brasil'}, 'interests': [{'id': 1, 'description': 'tecnology'}]}

print('CONTENT:', json.dumps(content))

print('MD5:', md5(str(content).encode('UTF-8')).hexdigest())
```

**The Python 2.7 result:**

```
('CONTENT:', {'interests': [{'id': 1, 'description': 'tecnology'}], 'age': 30, 'name': 'Marcelo', 'address': {'country': 'Brasil'}})

('MD5:', 'a396f6997fb420992d96b37e8f37938d')
```

**The Python 3.6 result:**

```
CONTENT: {'name': 'Marcelo', 'age': 30, 'address': {'country': 'Brasil'}, 'interests': [{'id': 1, 'description': 'tecnology'}]}

MD5: 40c601152725654148811749d9fc8878
```

*Edit:*

*I can't change the MD5 generated on Python 2. There is any way to reproduce the default order from Python 2 on Python 3?*

Comment: Dicts are not ordered, so the exact json output is not guaranteed even for the same Python version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python before 3.6, the dictionary keys are not ordered. So in Python 3.6, the keys maintain the order of their insertion (or in the case of a dictionary literal, how they appear in the literal). The Python 2.7 dictionary is unordered, so the looping order does not necessarily match insertion order.

If you were to reload the json dictionary in both cases, it would still be equal (dictionary equality does not depend on order).

So there is no error here. The difference is because of how dictionaries are ordered in different Python versions.

`json.dump` and `json.dumps` write the key-value pairs out in the dictionary looping order. So in order to have consistent looping order, it would be best to use the `collections.OrderedDict` type in order to achieve consistent ordering. If you are calling `json.load` to get dictionaries, you would also need to use `json.loads(text, object_hook=OrderedDict)`, which will then maintain ordering.

There is no trivial way to make Python 3 dictionaries use a Python 2 ordering, so moving both 2 and 3 code bases to use `OrderedDict` is a more maintainable solution.

Comment: I can't change the MD5 generated on Python 2. There is any way to reproduce the default order from Python 2 on Python 3?

Comment: @MarceloSoares There is no trivial/simple way to do that. I updated my answer to address a possible solution

Comment: @EdwardMinnix When you say no trivial way... Is it possible? :\